# When is the address of a string allocated?

Tags: c, memory-address

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[10];
    printf("The address of string is %x", str);
    return;
}
```

Every time I run the program, the same memory address shows up. Why is that so?
When does the memory get allotted?

Comment: can you tell me why you think it should not be so?

Comment: This it totally implementation specific.

Comment: Stack variables are allocated as soon as the function is called or the block of defitnition is entered. BTW: `main` should return some value. To print an address the format specifier `%p` should be used and the address should be cast to `(void *)`.

Comment: Now restart your machine and try to check address again? Is it matching?Or start few more programs and Try.

Comment: Printing addresses with any conversion specifier other than `%p` is undefined behavior, strictly speaking. You could be seeing whatever. Having said that, this is a subject for a book on operating systems. You need to learn about process memory.

Comment: Hint: Virtual address and physical address....

Comment: @AayushSharma Dynamically??? Where?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Since memory shoud be Dynamically allocated. The compilation only produces the assembly code but the machine should allocate a new memory every time I compile and run the program

Comment: @AayushSharma It does. But the addresses you get are relative to the program's process' virtual address space. And this one is always the same.

Comment: @SouravGhosh There is a technology whose name I don't recall. It is made to harden the burden to make use of stack overflow. It consists of randomly changing addresses/sizes on the stack. That might be one reason, but surely not one the OP thought of.

Comment: @glglgl Thankyou! I should learn more about it.

Comment: @glglgl Ahh..right....address space randomizer....or analogous. but still, dynamic and random are two different terminologies altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `str` has *function scope* and no storage class specifier, it has *automatic storage duration* by default. This means it exists as long as the execution doesn't leave its scope (the `main()` function). So the answer to your question is: The implementation must reserve memory for this variable whenever `main()` is entered. But the implementation would still be free to do it earlier, because this wouldn't lead to different observable behavior.

As for your other question, there's **nothing** in the specification of C telling you anything about addresses. Most likely, your implementation uses a *call stack* to store local (automatic) variables and in your system, this call stack is always located at the same virtual address. But this is guessing, an implementation can do whatever it likes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your program  causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You must use `%p` for printing pointers. Also, FWIW, if the supplied argument is anything other than a character pointer, you must cast the same to the `void *`.

That said, the memory allocation is implementation dependent. C standard does not mandate anything regarding the address range allocation scheme.